# Larger ticks for geom_line not showing as with geom_bar (when no data)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, visualization

I would like to reproduce a similar plot with geom_line instead of geom_bar.
For my geom_bar() I get this result:

```
year <- c(2001:2020)
has <- c(13980, 12170, 12340, 12700, 12503, 12747, 12894, 13072, 13174, 13330, 13090, 12558, 10843, 10342, 10454, 10262, 10473, 9007, 8534, 6806)
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(year, has))

  ggplot(data, aes(x=year, y= has)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",
  fill="lightblue")  +
  xlab("Year") + ylab("Hectares") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(2001,2020,1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(2500,5000,7500, 10000, 12500, 15000)) +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust=0.5))
```

[image: geom_bar()]

However, when I run exactly the same code but change geom_bar() with geom_line(), I get:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=year, y= has)) + 
  geom_line()  +
  xlab("Year") + ylab("Hectares") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(2001,2020,1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0, 2500,5000,7500, 10000, 12500, 15000)) +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust=0.5))
```

[image: geom_line]

As you see, now the plot doesn't show ticks going down until 2500, but it actually stops at the lowest value of has. This doesn't represent my data well. How could I adapt it to geom_line?

Comment: Try adding `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 15000))` line.

Comment: BTW, you may not get the above graphs using your data.